# Migrating from com.microsoft.azure.management.** to com.azure.resourcemanager.**

Tags: java, azure, azure-sdk-for-java

Currently migrating from com.microsoft.azure.management.** to com.azure.resourcemanager.** via https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/resourcemanager/docs/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md

Having problems with the following:

- UriQueryBuilder does not seem to have an equivalent in the new libraries. Is there a new replacement for it?
- RestClient is no longer available, and I've seen https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/resourcemanager/docs/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#custom-http-client. But how can I get the functionality of the old RestClient? i.e.

```
RestClient.Builder()
  .withBaseUrl(AzureEnvironment.AZURE, endpoint)
  .withSerializerAdapter(new AzureJacksonAdapter())
  .withReadTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
  .withCredentials(azureTokenCredentials)
```

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`RestClient` is replaced by `HttpClient` and `HttpPipeline`. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/29613

Currently, there is no replacement for `UriQueryBuilder` (but code says it was for internal use). See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/29596